# Symfony 5 - Bundle "WebProfilerBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled

Tags: php, symfony, environment

when I'm on prod environment, if I try to `cache:clear`, I've this error :

```
In FileLoader.php line 173:
                                                                                                                                                                                         
  Bundle "WebProfilerBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the "registerBundles()" method of your "App\Kernel.php" file? in @WebProfilerBundle/Res  
  ources/config/routing/wdt.xml (which is being imported from "C:\Users\user\Desktop\SylviaTest\config/routes/dev/web_profiler.yaml"). Make sure the "WebProfilerBundle/Resources/confi  
  g/routing/wdt.xml" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class. If the bundle is registered, make sure the bundle path "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/co  
  nfig/routing/wdt.xml" is not empty.   


In Kernel.php line 226:
                                                                                                                                                               
  Bundle "WebProfilerBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the "registerBundles()" method of your "App\Kernel.php" file?
```

I don't understand why...

**config/routes/dev/web_profiler.yaml:**

```
web_profiler_wdt:
    resource: '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml'
    prefix: /_wdt

web_profiler_profiler:
    resource: '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml'
    prefix: /_profiler
```

I haven't this file in **config/routes/prod** because I don't need it

And in my **config/bundles.php**, I've :

```
Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true, 'panther' => true],
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are you doing "bin/console cache:clear --env=prod" because cache:clear defaults to the dev enviroment which is what your messages seems to indicate is happening.

Comment: Yes, in my .env, the APP_ENV ils "prod". Next, if I do "bon/console cache:clear", it is clearing my prod environment and I've the error

Comment: So the console command first echos "Clearing the cache for the prod environment ..."?  Don't mean to harp on this but again it sure seems like a non-prod environment is being cleared.  If you have not already then you might try actually removing the var/cache directory completely.  Sometimes the previous cache can interfere with making a new one.

Comment: Okay I resolved the problem ! It was because of my kernel.php ! Thanks guy ! :)